# testdisk can see my partitions but cannot recover them all

Tags: linux, partition

my NAS got a corrupted partition table yesterday (I don't know the cause)

Now I run testdisk and I get this in the first analyze step:

```
Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55
```

However when I run quick scan it clearly sees my partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sdf - 15 GB / 14 GiB - CHS 15072 64 32
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  Linux                    0  63 31   243  63 30     497664
   Linux                    1   0  1 15070  63 32   30863360


Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
ext2 blocksize=1024 Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 254 MB / 243 MiB
```

partition 1 is also correctly seen as:

```
ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock Backup superblock, 15 GB / 14 G
```

So far everything is OK. However I cannot seem to recover both partitions.

If I select 0 as primary bootable (I think it is the /boot partition) I cannot make any valid selection for 1 (It does not allow me to chose either Logical or Extended)

On another (Debian) system I have this structure:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121602 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>* Linux                    0  65  2  2549 196 15   40957952
 P Linux                 2549 196 16 121535 178 51 1911508992
 P Linux Swap           121535 178 52 121600 215  7    1046512
```

But if I try to set this on the corrupted disk I get an error:

```
Disk /dev/sdf - 15 GB / 14 GiB - CHS 15072 64 32
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 * Linux                    0  63 31   243  63 30     497664
>P Linux                    1   0  1 15070  63 32   30863360


Structure: Bad. Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
```

When I select one as primary boot I get this on the next screen

```
Disk /dev/sdf - 15 GB / 14 GiB - CHS 15072 64 32

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 * Linux                    0  63 31   243  63 30     497664


 [  Quit  ] >[Deeper Search]  [ Write  ]
```

Suffice to say am **very** afraid to write only one partition to the device with the knowledge that it actually has two. How can I ensure that that second partition gets recovered as well?

Comment: Use Dos Spinrite is very good for such problems.

Answer (score 0):

All work with data recovery from broken disks should be done on raw image copies of the broken disk. Every step you try might save some data, but it might also break some more data. Whenever you find that an attempt have broken more data than it did recover you restart with a new copy of the original image file.

This kind of data recovery is time consuming and most times you will not be able to recover all your data. It is a lot quicker and easier to restore a backup, but that assumes you had a complete working backup.

Tools like ddrescue and photorec might be useful. You might also find some good live CD aimed against data recovery useful. One such example is systemrescuecd.

Comment: Of course you should also investigate why the disk got broken in the first place. Broken hardware? Malware? Clumsy user with root password?